# Vue components wont load ( Vuejs - Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Please I try to deploy my Laravel application in my hosted server using Vuejs in front-end, but I get a problem to load view components

When I run `php artisan serve` component loaded well, but the problem here when I close the command prompt the web server stop.

Someone know how can I load Vuejs component in Laravel app without `php artisan serve` command, or how to make the web server work in background when I close the command prompt.

Thanks.

Comment: Set up a web server (Apache/nginx). Or, if you want to run a process in the background, use `php artisan serve &`

Comment: I try to use `php artisan serve &` but the web server stop when I close the command prompt, @kerbholz how to setup the apache server, any idea ?

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya I use Mac cmd to coonect to my hosted server

Comment: Here's the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/) and here is some more info on [webserver configuration in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#web-server-configuration)

Comment: having the save problem i could not load vue component in v 5.8.3